# how to set up daily php functions or mysql queries

Tags: php, function, mysql, backup

I have wondered for a while now how to this. If I want to take weekly backups of all or many of my tables that stores values that changes every day in mysql. I also want to execute daily functions with php that update update values in my db.

I was thinking of making a stock investing function. Where I have fictional data as the value for various stocks, a value that changes randomly every day for every stock.

Maybe something like this for the last 9 days of the stock price curve.

```
CREATE TABLE `stocks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 

  `day_1` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
  `day_2` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',  
  `day_3` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
  `day_4` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
  `day_5` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',  
  `day_6` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
  `day_7` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
  `day_8` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '', 
  `day_9` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
```

if I could execute a php function once a day that made an array of the last 9 days of values. Then just change the `day_1` value and use `array_push($array, "new_stock_price");` then update the db with the new last_9_days values.

Comment: You should consider using two tables, one with `id,name` another with `stock_id,date,price`. The query `select * from stocks inner join prices on id=stock_id where date > dateadd(day,-9,getdate())` will get the last 9 days of stock prices. This is more flexible than your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a *nix system, use a CRON job.  On Windows, it's Scheduled Task...  Either will execute a script at a given time on any (or a specific) day.

I'd recommend a better table design:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`stocks`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`stocks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `stock_value` varchar(40) NOT NULL default '',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This way, if you want to see the last 9 values for a given stock name, use:

```
  SELECT s.name,
         s.value,
         s.created_date
    FROM STOCKS s
   WHERE s.name = ?
ORDER BY s.created_date DESC
   LIMIT 9
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a Linux / UNIX server, then you can set up a "cron job", which can run any command you like at a specified interval. This command could be a PHP script executed using the command line PHP interpreter).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

[What options are there for executing a PHP script at a certain time every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984622/what-options-are-there-for-executing-a-php-script-at-a-certain-time-every-day)

[How to implement cron in code (php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500699/how-to-implement-cron-in-code-php)