# Add data to a database, automatically remove after a certain time?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, timer

So, I've done quite a bit of googling on this topic, and I just can't find an answer. So, basically, I'm looking to make a small website, that will pull information from a HTML form, send it to a database, then after two hours, it will automatically delete itself. I have a basic theory on how this could work, but I can't figure out how to do it: I could pull the current time and date, add two hours to that, then put the time into an "expires" column in the database. Once the time is the one that is in the expires column, the data will be removed from the database. Sorry if this is a very "noobish" question, I'm still a bit new to databases with PHP.

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Just use a cron task which will remove every data > 2 hours.

Comment: You can try with cron. I think that will be a best solution.

Comment: @bfontaine If you mean the software, im using PHPMyAdmin, otherwise its just MySQL I guess...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html - use mysql event scheduler

Comment: @Vincent Decaux How could I do this? The thing is, I don't want all posts to get deleted every two hours, but each one will be deleted two hours after its created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a new timestamp column to your table which will automatically add the timestamp of when the row was created like so

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
   #your existing columns defined as before + this new column
   ts_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Now every time you create a row on this table, MySQL does all the work of recording when it was created.

Assuming you may not be able to create a cron job on your host you could then add the deletion code in the most obvious place in your existing site code to do the removal.

```
// remove old stale data
$sql = "DELETE FROM user
        WHERE ts_created < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 HOUR)";

if ( ! $mysqli->query($sql) ) {
    // log $mysqli->error somewhere
}
```

ALthough a cron job seems a good idea at first sight, in order to make sure things are always accurate on this table you would have to run it every 30 seconds or maybe even more often. That would get in the way of other activities on this table, if the site was busy that could be a problem, if it was not busy you would just be running the cron unnecessarily most of the time.

If you add the deletion code just before you present this information to the user at least it would only be run when required and you would also ensure that the table was always accurate at the time the data was presented to the user.

Comment: Yeah, I probably can't use cron jobs, as my  web host only allows once an hour or more... Only thing is, that seems pretty complicated..

Comment: Actually, not **too** complicated, but I have my table already made in PHPMyAdmin. So if I just add a current timestamp, can it just be set every time new data is added

Comment: Yes that is what will happen. You may need to clear out the rows that existed prior to the table change manually though

Comment: OK, thanks! Could you give me a run-down of the exact code I should put and where?(sorry, I'm a noob)

Comment: I assume you mean the PHP code to execute the DELETE. Well not without some idea of your existing PHP code I cant.

Comment: Well, um, here: (I removed database login info) pastebin.com/Hz0VkhP1

Comment: This should really have been another question but see my amended answer. I would add this just above the `// Insert our data` comment

Comment: See the PHP code in my answer, that is all you need to add or http://pastebin.com/ubTZ97Z0

Comment: OK, last thing.. Do I need to do anything else that replace my file with your edited version?

Comment: Ony change the database to add the new field

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure the scheduler starts when MySQL is launched with the command-line option --event-scheduler=ON or setting event_scheduler=ON in your MySQL configuration file (my.cnf or my.ini on Windows).
Run this query statement in mysql

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Create an mysql event scheduler using following - this will behave like Cron Job but actually it is a mysql trigger on specific interval. This is triggered from mysql server.

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
 ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'Clears out sessions table each hour.'
DO
  DELETE FROM table_name WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(remove_time) > 120
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Pardon my explaination - I myself have implemented this just now and it worked.

Comment: please do mark my answer as correct if this answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column remove_time (`DATETIME`) and set the time you want the row to be deleted. Than use cron (configuration depends on webhosting you have) to run this query (probably as poart of PHP script):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE remove_time <= NOW()
```

You can configure cron to run every minute (or less/more, depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

1. Try implementing a **cron** which will run at specified time automatically to check and delete the rows whose **created_at** is less than the **current_time** by 2 hours.
2. On how to implement cron, check **Skilldrick's** answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500699/how-to-implement-cron-in-code-php)

Thank you 
:)

Comment: What do I put inside cron.php?

Comment: EDIT: I guess I put the delete part in there... Anyway, so I should add created_at and current_time to my table?

Comment: Add only **created_at** in your database. The **current_time** variable will be set in php --> `$current_time = time() ;` This will return you the Unix timestamp.The next step is to calculate the *unix timestamp* **2 hours** before the current timestamp,say `$temp_timestamp`. And finally, delete the fields whose **created_at** is less than that the `$temp_timestamp`.