# Deleting a whole row with timer

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table in MySQL - phpmyadmin like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_test` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `CreationDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I would like to add a `DeleteTimer` as well to this table. Lets say an ID is created and its `Description` is null/empty, so I would like to add DeleteTimer = 7 days for this particular ID. After 7 days, it checks if the Description of this ID is still null and then that ID with its whole row gets deleted automatically.

From what I have found out [How to implement cron in code (php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500699/how-to-implement-cron-in-code-php) is to implement a cron job with a time limit of 7 days so as the row that gets deleted automatically. But how do I implement this in phpmyadmin? Since I am hosting my own server, writing a php code would be better for this cron job or doing it inside phpmyadmin is better?

```
// remove old stale data
$sql = "DELETE FROM table_test
        WHERE CreationDate< DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 HOUR)"; //To add 7 days here

if ( ! $mysqli->query($sql) ) {
    // log $mysqli->error somewhere
}
```

Comment: You can not do this in phpmyadmin. It is only for administrating your DB's, you need to write wanted logic in  `.php` file and execute it with cron job how often you want. Cron job is servers.

Comment: @ikiK can you explain with a tutorial link or an example of how to do this?

Comment: you can also use the MySQL scheduler in interval mode https://mariadb.com/kb/en/event-scheduler/

Comment: @ikiK it is just a hosting server created here ```https://kas.all-inkl.com/```

Comment: That really does not mean anything to me what you just shared, Sorry. See what kind of server you have, linux, windows, or something else, and research how to execute php file as cron job.  Then see what your hosting is offering as tools for this. On C-panel for example setting up a cron job is really easy... Or maybe you will need to do SSH connection to your server to set it up... You need to do some re-search, to many unknowns here...

Comment: Ah sorry i thought you asked about hosting website. I use windows and so i guess i have to check on how to execute php as cron job.

Comment: If you want to achieve the deletion in mysql only, then what was wrong with the detailed answer using mysql's built-in scheduler? You deleted that question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you just add a view to see non-deleted records:

```
create view v_table_test as
    select t.*
    from table_test t
    where CreationDate >= now() - interval 7 day;
```

You can access this view and see the non-deleted records.  This has an advantage over actually deleting the records, because it is up-to-date -- you don't have to worry about delays of jobs or server load.

Then, periodically -- say once per week when the load on the system is low -- delete the old records.  You can just schedule this as a job in the database or using `cron` or whatever method you like.

Comment: Hey thanks! I shall try using views. May I know how can one add  "- interval 7 days". Should it be related to number of seconds passed since the creation date or can we just add a particular date in the format DD/MM/YYYY and then the system can calculate the days passed? If you know this, then please edit your answer to explain how can one achieve this :)

Comment: @Saif . . . I have no idea what your comment is asking.  You use `now() - interval 7 day` to subtract seven days.  That's all:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6554ecca382510094b7cdb8ee3f197fa.

Comment: Ah cool thank you!